# Access variables from print_r in php

Tags: php

I got a print_r($result) output as follows:

```
stdClass Object ( 
    [balance] => 998 
    [batch_id] => 243941208 
    [cost] => 1 
    [num_messages] => 1 
    [message] => stdClass Object ( 
        [num_parts] => 1 
        [sender] => TMTLCO 
        [content] => @U0D070D240D4D00200D120D300D4100200D1F0D460D380D4D0D310D4D0D310D4D002000200D060D230D4D 
    ) 
    [receipt_url] => 
    [custom] => 
    [messages] => Array ( 
        [0] => stdClass Object ( 
            [id] => 117250619 
            [recipient] => XXXXXXXX 
        ) 
    ) 
    [status] => success 
)
```

I could echo the following and get correct output:

```
echo $result->balance;
echo $result->num_messages;
```

But the following is not working??

```
echo $result->message->sender;
echo $result->messages->recipient;
echo $result->messages->status;
```

What am i doing wrong ??

Comment: `print_r()` is for checking purposes only. I think your query should be `$result->messages[0]->sender`

Comment: It's in the same level, where balance and num_message are, `echo $result->status;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Miss the `0` which is an array. For accessing `recipient` you need to add one more Dimension into your `$result` array.

Messages has a one more array which you miss to navigate. So try with this,

```
echo $result->message->sender;
echo $result->messages[0]->recipient;
echo $result->status;
```

Comment: Thanks. The status code was not correct.
It was echo $result->messages[0]->recipient;  AND echo $result->status;